# How to fix 'Errors in solution after fresh installation of visual studio 2019"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have installed a new Visual Studio 2019. Everything seems to work fine. But there is one big problem. When I connected to our company projects, on server side solution, everything is ok and build solution is succesfull. But when I wanted to build Client side solution, I got about 80 errors. Many of them are from Interaction Windows .. 
Other kolegues does not have any problems.

Errors:

[image]

I tried actually to close visual studio, remove bin and obj folders, restart visual studio, clean solution and build it again. But it does not work :(.

This topic have no code.

I expect to succesfull build client side solution.

Comment: Try to clean and regenerate your solution, and be sure that all of your dll files are in the folder

Comment: @taktak I actually tried remove bin and obj from solution, clean and rebuild solution twice. It does not work :/ And Im sure all dll are in the folder.

Comment: And when you go in your codes, they are probably red underlined. Put your cursor over the red line and try to solve your issue by what it asks you to add

Comment: Have any nuget packages been restored?

Comment: Their tons of problems people are facing with client-side application load in VS 2019. Kindly check your ,csproj file and also check do you have full permission on the folder.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I will check that.

Comment: Maybe you have to add some of those .dll files manually. VS -> Solution Explorer -> References -> right click -> Add References and find you .dll fiels

Comment: @Gray_Rhino I try check all references in all projects, if any will be displayed as yellow, then there will be problem.

Comment: I tried to reinstall Blend SDK for System.Windows.Interactivity in which was yellow triangle. And it worked!

Comment: Clean the solution. Then make sure there are no background tasks running (there is a small icon near Ready that shows if anything is running like code analysis). After that, do a Rebuild Solution.

Comment: @DanielCapek I know, that has happened to me as well (in my case they were Autodest API files). Those References are missing so you have to add them again